# Missing attributes when using JIRA Python API

Tags: python, api, jira

I've been experimenting a bit with the Python API for JIRA (love it), and am finding inconsistencies in what it returned when using jira.issue as opposed to jira.search_issues

For example, I have this simple code, which finds me all open subtasks where the parent is closed:

```
from jira import JIRA
import re

jira_options = {
    'server': 'http://myserver:8081/jira'
}

jira = JIRA(options=jira_options, basic_auth=('dwaynek','bigsecret'))

issues = jira.search_issues('issuetype=Sub-task and status!=Closed and project=proj1 order by assignee')

for i in issues:
    parentIssue = jira.issue(i.fields.parent)
    print("\t- parent issue %s is %s" % (i.fields.parent, parentIssue.fields.status.name))
    print("Verifying %s subtask %s assigned to %s"%(i.fields.status,i, i.fields.assignee.name))

    # print for debugging
    print(dir(parentIssue.fields))
    print(dir(i.fields))

    print("\t- parent %s is %s and was assigned to %s" % (i.fields.parent, parentIssue.fields.status.name, parentIssue.fields.assignee.name))
```

produces output, and an error like this:

```
        - parent issue BUG-19834 is Closed
Verifying Open subtask BUG-19836 assigned to andreas

['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'issuetype', 'priority', 'status', 'summary']

['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'aggregateprogress', 'aggregatetimeestimate', 'aggregatetimeoriginalestimate', 'aggregatetimespent', 'assignee', 'components', 'created', 'creator', 'customfield_10000', 'customfield_10001', 'customfield_10002', 'customfield_10006', 'customfield_10100', 'customfield_10102', 'customfield_10103', 'customfield_10105', 'customfield_10106', 'customfield_10107', 'customfield_10108', 'customfield_10109', 'customfield_10110', 'customfield_10111', 'customfield_10202', 'customfield_10300', 'customfield_10301', 'customfield_10302', 'customfield_10400', 'customfield_10500', 'customfield_10600', 'customfield_10601', 'customfield_10602', 'customfield_10700', 'customfield_10900', 'customfield_11000', 'description', 'fixVersions', 'issuelinks', 'issuetype', 'labels', 'lastViewed', 'parent', 'priority', 'progress', 'project', 'reporter', 'resolution', 'resolutiondate', 'status', 'subtasks', 'summary', 'timeestimate', 'timeoriginalestimate', 'timespent', 'updated', 'versions', 'watches', 'workratio']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "find_closed_parents.py", line 25, in <module>
    print("\t- parent %s is %s and was assigned to %s" % (i.fields.parent, parentIssue.fields.status.name, parentIssue.fields.assignee.name))
AttributeError: type object 'PropertyHolder' has no attribute 'assignee'
```

NOTE: the dictionaries that I receive hold different elements.  The dict received from search_issues seems to return a lot more attributes than the one received from jira.issue()

Why is this?  I've even tried specifying the fields in the call to jira.issue() with no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?